# What grammar does ‘it’ in: “It's Amy” fall under?

Tags: personal-pronouns, dummy-it

> Q: Who is in the room?
>   A: (1) Is Amy (2) It's Amy (3) Amy is (4) Amy

Please explain the reason why each answer is right/wrong.
I normally answer with (2), but however, the proper answer according to the teacher is (3).

Now, I've never heard anyone answer like that nor have I ever read it.

The only reason why I can think so it can't be (2) is because we can't refer to a person as [It]. And the reason why I think (3) is right is because we've just simply cut the sentence short, Amy is [in the room].

Can someone explain with proper grammar why the answer is (3) and not (2).

Comment: Haven't you asked this before? What happened?

Comment: 2,3,4 all work but stylistically different. 1 is way off.

Comment: "Who's there? It's me". _It_ can certainly refer to persons.

Comment: It sound as if the teacher is not teaching you English, the language that millions of people speak, but "English", a language that somebody has attempted to define in a book. Hard luck.

Comment: @Barrie It was deleted as a homework question as I forgot to add the extra information to the question. I should have been specific.

Comment: @Colin This is actually a test question from my sister's English test. The teachers here just teach straight from the textbook which in my opinion isn't really teaching English. English is a language that should be used and not "remembered off by heart". But sadly, that is how English is being taught in Asia.

Answer (score 2):

In English, the grammatical variant in response to the question "Who is it?" is (2). Utterances (3) and (4) are also grammatical in other circumstances, but not as an answer to that question.

Now, the reason for this falls out of how English syntax works; other languages can use the direct equivalents of one of the other variants.

- When you use **"be" and have only a predicate** but not an explicit subject (because either the implied subject is understood from a previous utterance as in this case, or because there is simply no logical subject), **English does not allow the predicate to be promoted to the subject**. Other languages allow or require this (so e.g. in Spanish, the equivalent of "it's me" is *yo soy*).
- English is not a pro-drop language and requires a **dummy subject** to be present in cases such as existentials ("*there* is no milk"), weather verbs ("*it* is snowing") and cleft sentences ("*it*'s difficult, learning English", "*it* was Mary who came"). We've said that in the equivalent of Spanish *yo soy*, English doesn't allow the predicate to become the subject. That might lead us to expect "is me". But English requires a dummy subject, so you end up with "it's me". And similarly, "it's them", "it's Mary" etc. In pro-drop languages there may be no overt subject at all in these cases. For example, in Spanish *llueve* ("it's raining"), there's no possible subject, not even a 'neutral' one.
- English generally has the order Subject-Verb except for interrogative forms and one or two other exceptional cases. Notably, the word order in English doesn't generally depend on information structure (the status of items as being new/old information etc), whereas in other languages, the word order is influenced far more by such factors. So this essentially rules out (1) unless it is a question ("I'm going swimming. Is Amy?"), and contrasts with e.g. Spanish where depending on the circumstances either *yo soy* or *soy yo* is potentially possible (without being a question).

Comment: An excellent answer, but I don't agree that (3) or (4) are inappropriate as a reply to the question.

Comment: This is all true, but Karen's question was "Who is in the room?", not "Who is it?"...

Comment: Haha oops -- missed that crucial bit! :)

Comment: Some how when we ask "who is in the room", a feeling that we know  it's referred to a person subject. When asking "Who is it", the "it" can kind of refer to any subject?

Comment: @Karen - Essentially, because the "it" doesn't really refer to anything as such, just as if I say "There's a problem", the "there" doesn't really 'refer' to anything. From a syntactic point of view, it is essentially a 'dummy filler' for the subject position of the sentence. (Informally, in junior school grammar we sometimes think of the 'subject' of a sentence as being 'what the sentence is about', but really that's not actually true, as these examples illustrate.)